# Django Social Auth - Not Enough Values To Unpack When Trying To Send Email

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

I'm using the Django-Python Social Auth app and i'm trying to extend my pipeline so that when a user signs up using Facebook, they are simultaneously signed up to my Mailchimp mailing list (and sent an email to verify).  This works fine if a user signs up using traditional input methods--but not via Social auth.and is returning this error:

`ValueError at /oauth/complete/facebook/
not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

here is full stack trace:

```
File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\social_django\utils.py" in wrapper
  49.             return func(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\social_django\views.py" in complete
  33.                        *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\social_core\actions.py" in do_complete
  41.         user = backend.complete(user=user, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\base.py" in complete
  40.         return self.auth_complete(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\social_core\utils.py" in wrapper
  252.             return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\facebook.py" in auth_complete
  111.         return self.do_auth(access_token, response, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\facebook.py" in do_auth
  153.         return self.strategy.authenticate(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\social_django\strategy.py" in authenticate
  107.         return authenticate(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py" in authenticate
  70.             user = _authenticate_with_backend(backend, backend_path, request, credentials)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py" in _authenticate_with_backend
  116.     return backend.authenticate(*args, **credentials)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\base.py" in authenticate
  80.         return self.pipeline(pipeline, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\base.py" in pipeline
  83.         out = self.run_pipeline(pipeline, pipeline_index, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\base.py" in run_pipeline
  112.             func = module_member(name)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\social_core\utils.py" in module_member
  57.     mod, member = name.rsplit('.', 1)

Exception Type: ValueError at /oauth/complete/facebook/
Exception Value: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

My pipeline looks like so:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',  # <--- enable this one
    'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'sendsub',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
```

you can see that I've added a `sendsub` function which is based on this function---and somewhat modeled [off this page here](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html#extending-the-pipeline)

```
def sendsub(backend, user, response, *args, **kwargs):
    profile = user.get_profile()
    email = profile.email
    thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=())
    thread.daemon = True                     
    thread.start()                                 

    def run(self):
        API_KEY = settings.MAILCHIMP_API_KEY
        LIST_ID = settings.MAILCHIMP_SUBSCRIBE_LIST_ID
        api = mailchimp.Mailchimp(API_KEY)
        try:
            api.lists.subscribe(LIST_ID, {'email': self.email})
        except:
            return False
```

again this `sendsub` function is working correctly when applied to my regular registration page an user model..here is the function (slight difference).

```
class SendSubscribeMail(object):
    def __init__(self, email):
        self.email = email
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=())
        thread.daemon = True                     
        thread.start()                                 

    def run(self):
        API_KEY = settings.MAILCHIMP_API_KEY
        LIST_ID = settings.MAILCHIMP_SUBSCRIBE_LIST_ID
        api = mailchimp.Mailchimp(API_KEY)
        try:
            api.lists.subscribe(LIST_ID, {'email': self.email})
        except:
            return False
```

Comment: an essential piece of information is missing from your question. A full stack trace

Comment: ok one second will add in a moment--thanks

Comment: All updated with full errors. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the error itself comes from social auth. But that's because you are not giving it the right data.

```
mod, member = name.rsplit('.', 1)
```

It's trying to split the name into two, there isn't a dot in the name so you cannot get two parts out of it. So it's impossible to assign to mod and member. Now we know the problem, but we still have a long way to goto solve it. The first step is to identify the culprit. I would say it's right here.

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=())
thread.daemon = True                     
thread.start()
```

Creating your own threads in a web app is a very dangerous thing to do. You should either do this task synchronously, or you should delegate to a task queue and let it happen completely asynchronously.

Comment: thanks for your help.  i was following this tutorial --https://djangopy.org/package-of-week/how-to-integrate-mailchimp-on-django-to-increase-subscribers/  and honestly don't know a heck of a lot about threading, so interesting to learn that.  Right now I have separate functions to add a user to a mailchimp list (one for a regular signup and another when they run through social auth).  I think probably best to run a task to add a user to mailchimp list upon any new signup in django.  Any advice for this?  Is there a way to check if a new user is added asynchronously?  Or is that a bad idea?

Comment: I think for the moment you probably ought to concentrate on getting it done synchronously. ONce you are more familiar with the framework, you can explore celery

Comment: ahh..yes had been looking into celery.  I did just add a post_save signal to my user model, to add a user to the mailchimp list..and it appears to be working for all of my signups (normal + facebook) see any issues doing it that way?  `@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def send_sub(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created', True):
        email = kwargs.get('instance').email
        SendSubscribeMail(email)`

Comment: nopes using signals is a pretty standard and usefull way. Good choice

Answer (score 2):

Entries in `SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE` should be in the form of an import path, in this case the error is caused becuase `sendsub` is not a proper import path, you need to specify the module it's defined like `module.sendsub`.

In order to verify that the import path is correct, you should be able to run the same in a django shell in the form `import module.sendsub` and it should successfully import it.

Comment: belated thanks for the comment!  so, if understand correctly i need to put my code in a module.  i created a utils folder with a utils file and a __init__ file.  in shell if i do an import utils.utils.sendsub i get a 'no module named .. and utils.utils is not a package...ugh FORGOT some of this stuff---

Comment: sorry confusing module---with package...i put the utils file in my root folder and appears to be working.  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hope this isn't too late. But in `settings.py`, make sure that `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` have a comma behind it, otherwise it's taken as a string, and hence causes the error.